# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused using ipv6 address

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have setup a Ubuntu server and I am trying to connect to the db but keep getting the connection refused error. I can log in to mysql through the terminal using the same username and password with no problems and I also setup a connection via workbench with the same user.
This is a hosted server.
The server connects to a ipv6 address and php 7.1.
I can see that the default port is 3306
Code is below

```
$dbhost = '[ipv6 address]';
$dbuser = 'User';
$dbpass = 'user1';
$usedb = '2hourworkday_Prod';

$conn = mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$usedb");
```

I have done this many times before with no problems but I started using a new hosting provider (vultr) and it's the first time i'm connecting to a ipv6 address. Anyone else have this problem before?

Comment: Try using the command line mysql -uusername -p and type the password when it prompts –

Comment: Yes i can connect through the command line

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you check whether your host support IPv6 address or not by: http://ipv6-test.com/

If not, you should add an IPV6 DNS AAAA record to the domain (that used for your hosting).